# Passing ID Attributes

Tags: jquery, scope

I am grabbing divs using the .each function, but I am having trouble passing the ID I get to my modal box function.  Here is the code:

```
(function() {
$('div.heriyah').each(function() { 
$(this).html('<div class="add"><div id="add_button_container"><div id="add_button" class="edit_links">+ ADD NEW CONTENT</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="placeable"></div></div>');

$('.add').click(function() {
$.fallr('show', {
          content     :  '<iframe width="620" height="600" src="<? echo $URL ?>/manage_content.php?id=<? echo $pageID; ?>&div='+$(this).attr('id')+'"></iframe>',
          width       : 620 + 5, // 100 = for width padding
          height         : 600,
          closeKey        : true,
          closeOverlay    : true,
          buttons     : {}
}); 
}); 

});
```

})();

I get `Undefined` if I request the variable inside my modal box.

I use this:

```
'+$(this).attr('id')+'
```

To grab the id inside my modal box function.

Thanks,
Drummer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `fallr` is but try changing your code to this:

```
    (function() {
    $('div.heriyah').each(function() { 
    $(this).html('<div class="add"><div id="add_button_container"><div id="add_button" class="edit_links">+ ADD NEW CONTENT</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="placeable"></div></div>'); 

    var curID = $(this).attr('id');//get the id before you go into fallr

    $('.add').click(function() {
    $.fallr('show', {
              content     :  '<iframe width="620" height="600" src="<? echo $URL ?>/manage_content.php?id=<? echo $pageID; ?>&div='+curID +'"></iframe>',
              width       : 620 + 5, // 100 = for width padding
              height         : 600,
              closeKey        : true,
              closeOverlay    : true,
              buttons     : {}
    }); 
    }); 

    }); 
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense.  I learned something new today!

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing `$(this)` from within the SECOND anonymous function.  So you are asking for the `$(this)` of .add not the div.heriyah  That is why you're not getting the ID.

Answer (score 0):

It is because `this is now refering to fallr

```
$('.add').click(function() {
    var _this = $(this);
    $.fallr('show', {
              content     :  '/manage_content.php?id=&div='+_this+'">',
              width       : 620 + 5, // 100 = for width padding
              height         : 600,
              closeKey        : true,
              closeOverlay    : true,
              buttons     : {}
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point in your code where you are building the `iframe`, `$(this)` will be the value of `$('.add')`, **not** your original `div` tag.

Before you bind the click event, just create a new variable and store `$(this).attr('id')`, and use that value instead.

Answer (score 0):

classic scope issue - You're trying to get the `id` attribute of the '.add' element because you're in that scope.

Cache the $(this) in the `.each` function and use that:

```
$('div.heriyah').each(function() {
$(this).html('<div class="add"><div id="add_button_container"><div id="add_button"      class="edit_links">+ ADD NEW CONTENT</div></div></div><div class="clear"></div><div class="placeable"></div></div>');

var that = $(this);

$('.add').click(function() {
    $.fallr('show', {
          content     :  '<iframe width="620" height="600" src="<? echo $URL ?>/manage_content.php?id=<? echo $pageID; ?>&div='+that.attr('id')+'"></iframe>',
          width       : 620 + 5, // 100 = for width padding
          height         : 600,
          closeKey        : true,
          closeOverlay    : true,
          buttons     : {}
}); 
    }); 

});
```